# Angular 2 - Tour of heroes: how object info is coming by only selecting <li>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am going through the documentation of angular 4 project "Tour of Heroes" https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html .

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)">{{hero.name}}</li>
```

Here what is happening when I select any HERO the function `onSelect()` initiates and passes the particular "hero" object and then it assigns to the `selectedHero` to show that particular info using `this` functionality.

I want to know how that particular information about "hero" we are getting (so that we can pass it through `onSelect()` function) by only selecting that the HERO

Comment: The doc explains it all here https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2#selecting-a-hero

Comment: this is to simple  in this tutorial it self explained very  well@user3526127

Comment: Could you please explain. I am new to Javascript and Angular. In the document it is given that "hero" object is passed but I want to know what is happening behind. I mean on selecting particular "li" we get "hero" object also... but how?

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand your question, but `(click)` is a click event. This means that when you click on the html element the event is attached to, it fires the specified function. That element has the data for each hero because the *ngFor is referencing the existing `heroes` array which exists in the typescript. *ngFor is like a for loop, so `hero` here refers to each individual hero, which contains the data. This data is passed to `onSelect` when the element is clicked

Comment: yes this is the thing I wanted to know... does that particular "li" contains data of individual hero? but in console I couldn't find that data if we get it through getQuerySelector. Could you please tell me how can we show that data in the console?

Comment: I wouldn't say the 'li' contains the data, but it has access to the data that is retrieved from the *ngFor loop. The interpolation `{{}}` binds to the data. You must have an `onSelect` method in your TypeScript, within that method you could add something like `console.log(hero)` or `console.log(hero.name)` and it should show the data in the console when the 'li' is clicked.

Comment: I checked nothing is coming into the console. Can anyone explain the whole story behind it - from clicking to capturing data. How hero data is attached with the 'li'? How can I see the whole process into the console or any other place? How can I display the hero data in the console? The element has the data for each hero then where the data is stored in the dom tree? Kindly explain me this whole mess.

Comment: If anyone can explain it with the core javascript will be better.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure where you are confused, but let's break down what this line is doing.

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)">{{hero.name}}</li>
```

First of all, the *ngFor command creates a number of list elements equal to the length of the "heroes" array. This is done using Angular's structural directives.

In clearer steps, the *ngFor statement looks at this line "let hero of heroes."
What this statement means is that for every variable in the array, heroes, a new < li > element is created. Then, **within the scope of that created < li > element**, it creates a variable "hero" which references the corresponding variable within the heroes array. This "hero" variable can be used and referenced only within that created < li > element.

For example, if you had an Array like this: myNumArray = [1,5,7,8],
and you had a list like this

```
<li *ngFor="let num of myNumArray" (click)="console.log(num)">{{num}}</li>
```

It would print out

1

5

7

8

Because the "num" variable in each < li > element refers back to the respective variable of myNumArray that was assigned when the element was created suing the *ngFor. Additionally, each < li > element would have a click event that logs **its instance of num** to the console. Clicking on 1, would log "1," clicking on 5 would log "5," and so on.

The reason you can refer to this local variable "hero" in the same element tag that the "ngFor" is called is because of some templating magic in Angular. the * symbol actually hops **outside** the element in which it was called and creates a template. You can read more about the utilization of * and ngFor here: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-asterisk--prefix

Hopefully this answers your question and explains how each particular "hero" info is created, and how they are distinct from each other.

Comment: Excellent... now I can understand the whole thing clearly... If we take any object in place of array, we can get value of the property through that corresponding <li> in this interpolation {{ }}. Thanks Lars... Pretty Clear